# Wordpress create database with FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to create a wordpress plugin that will use two databases I need them to have FOREIGN KEY but cannot get the plugin to create them only if I remove the FOREIGN KEY can I get them to create a table.

```
global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'aa_accessform';
  $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'aa_formcomments';

  $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $wpdb->query(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
            id              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            customer_id     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            appointment_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            notes TEXT,
            token VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
        ) ENGINE = INNODB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
        COLLATE = utf8_general_ci"
    );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
    $wpdb->query(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name2 (
            id              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            customer_codes__id     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            appointment_codes_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            notes TEXT,
            token VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY  (id),
            FOREIGN KEY  (customer_codes__id) REFERENCES ".$table_name." (id)
        ) ENGINE = INNODB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
        COLLATE = utf8_general_ci"
    );
    dbDelta( $sql );
```

I would love to know what is wrong.

Comment: Any change if you remove the quotes  `..REFERENCES  $table_name(id)....`

Comment: The definitions look correct. Have you attempted to create them outside the context of PHP, using a plain MySQL client? If the first table does not successfully create, or it already existed with a different definition, the second would fail.

Comment: Creating your tables in sqlfiddle, (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3612) I did encounter "multiple primary key defined", because you have `PRIMARY KEY` both in the definition of `id` in `$table_name2`, and repeated later just before the `FOREIGN KEY` definition. Removing `PRIMARY KEY (id)` worked, but is inconsistent with you having had to remove the FK. In any case though, you should check for errors after both statements to find out what error MySQL is reporting.

Comment: @mihai still same with when I remove the "" .. 
It does not generate the second table only the first.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski your code works inside of mysql and creates both tables I have copied this and removed the KEY but still does not work in wordpress plugin.

Comment: You need to check for errors after the `$wpdb->query()` calls then to find out what it doesn't like. I think it's `$wpdb->last_error`? Don't know much about wordpress.

Comment: I just noticed you are calling `dbDelta($sql)` but the variable `$sql` is not defined in your code. Examples [in these docs here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) use `dbDelta()` to execute the statement, not `$wpdb->query()`.

Comment: True I have now removed this. I have also turned on wordpress debug but yet to get it working. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100301/discussion-between-sam-miller-and-michael-berkowski).

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer and is now working the below works.

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'aa_accessform';
  $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'aa_formcomments';

  
    $wpdb->query(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
        id              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        customer_id     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        appointment_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        notes TEXT,
        token VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE = INNODB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
    COLLATE = utf8_general_ci"
);
  
dbDelta();

$wpdb->query(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name2 (
        id              INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        customer_codes_id     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        appointment_codes_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        notes TEXT,
        token VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY  (customer_codes_id) REFERENCES $table_name(id)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
    COLLATE = utf8_general_ci"
);

dbDelta();
```

Notice the below line is the real fix

```
FOREIGN KEY  (customer_codes_id) REFERENCES $table_name(id) //correct
```

the incorrect line below is:

```
FOREIGN KEY  (customer_codes__id) REFERENCES ".$table_name." (id) //wrong
```

Comment: Thanks! it helped me.

Comment: Since you are creating the tables with `$wpdb->query()` you can remove the calls to `dbDelta()`. If you want to use `dbDelta()` then you have to pass it a SQL statement or an array of SQL statements. However, `dbDelta()` does not support the use of foreign keys. It is primarily used for simple table creations and automatic table modifications for plugin upgrades; however, more complex scenarios (such as foreign keys, removing columns, etc.) are not handled by it.

Comment: See this answer for more details on [dbDelta support for FOREIGN KEY](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52783/dbdelta-support-for-foreign-key)